# Proving unit with some condition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity $1$ and let $a\in R$. If there exists a unique $b\in R$ such that $ab=1$, prove that $ba=1$ and $a$ is a unit.

Comment: You'll probably have more luck getting an answer if you include your thoughts and what you've tried. (Also, have you forgotten a hypothesis? That $R$ has no nonzero zero-divisors, perhaps?)

Comment: If I can prove ba=1then I can say a is an unit bt how shall I prove ba=1 Pls give me hints

Comment: Well I'm not sure if it's true as stated; I don't know a solution off the top of my head. If it is true, you'll need to use uniqueness of $b$ in an essential way (it's false for certain without that hypothesis).

Comment: Pls give me proper solution.I don't understand.Pls

Comment: This user (or program, possibly) has been posting numerous questions in the same bad format, most of them duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the product $a$$($$b$$a$$-$$1$$+$$b$$)$.then $a$$($$b$$a$$-$$1$$+$$b$$)$$=$$a$$b$$a$$-$$a$$+$$a$$b$$=$$($$a$$b$$)$$a$$-$$a$$+$$1$$=$$a$$-$$a$$+$$1$$=$$1$.As $b$ is unique and $a$$b$$=$$1$ implies that $b$$a$$-$$1$$+$$b$$=$$b$ and by cancellation law we get $b$$a$$=$$1$.and the proof is complete.